# What point of equilibrium the particle will be close to after a sufficiently long time?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> A particle is moving on the $x$-axis such that $$\frac {dx} {dt} = (x - 1) (x + 2) (x - 3).$$ Here $x$ denotes the $x$-coordinate of the particle and $t$ denotes time. The particle is so positioned
> initially that it does not wander off to infinity. Which point of equilibrium will it be close to after a sufficiently long time?

I have solved the differential equation and found that $$\frac {|x-3|^{\frac {1} {10}} |x + 2|^{\frac {1} {15}}} {|x - 1|^{\frac {1} {6}}} = Ce^t$$ where $C$ is some arbitrary constant to be determined by the given initial condition. But I failed to understand the initial condition here. Could anyone please help me in this regard?

Comment: No need to solve the ODE! Just draw the **phase portrait**, and the answer should hopefully become obvious.

Comment: @Hans Lundmark what do you mean by **phase portrait**? Actually I am not familiar with such kind of things. Could you please explain a bit more? Thanks.

Comment: You only need to inspect the sign of $x'$. Since $x' > 0$ for $x > 3$, if $x(0) > 3$, $x(t) \to \infty$ as $t \to \infty$. Similiarly, if $x(0) < -2$, $x(t) \to -\infty$ as $t \to \infty$. If $-2 < x(0) < 3$, convince yourself $x'$ always has the right sign to move towards the middle fixed point $x = 1$.

Comment: Thinking more about it. If $x(0) > 3$ (or $< -2)$, $x(t)$ dosen't diverge to $\pm \infty$ as $t \to \infty$. It does that in finite time! In any event, this doesn't affect the behavior for $-2 < x(0) < 3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say initially the particle is at $x_0$ (at $t=0$).

> The particle is so positioned initially that it does not wander off to infinity.

This means $x_0 \ne 1$ so that you have a finite value for $C$.

Now as $t\to \infty$ the RHS of solution $\to \infty$ due to the term $e^t$.

Since $x$ is a function of $t$, the only way this could happen if $x(t) \to 1$ as $t\to \infty$. This means the particle will be near $x=1$ after a long time.

Comment: You need also to say that in LHS the numerator and the denominator will have same degree of $x.$ That's why the LHS can go to infinity for sufficiently large $t$ if and only if $x(t) \to 1$ as $t \to \infty.$ But the reasoning is very nice. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I think the numerator (or $x(t) $) can not go to infinity because of the initial condition "The particle is so positioned initially that it does not wander off to infinity", so the only possibility is $x\to 1$.